# Upload Image on Hosting server using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I need some help for upload an image.

I have two different application

- Springboot application - Running on my dedicated Server
- Angular-6 Application - Running on my Cloud Server

I need to upload an image from my spring-boot app to my Angular-6 assets folder (assets folder is like resource folder of our spring-boot app)

In application.properties I have declare upload location like profile_path=D:/documents/profile/ (Its working file with My File System path)

```
    if (!profileImage.isEmpty()) {

        String fileName = profileImage.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileExtenstion = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);

        InputStream is = profileImage.getInputStream();

        Files.copy(is, Paths.get(profile_path + userDetailId + "." + fileExtenstion),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        profileImagePath = profile_path + userDetailId + "." + fileExtenstion;
    }
```

Now, The problem is with the Cloud Server path
How can I upload on http://www.example.com/documents/profiles/ OR //103.XXX.XX.XX/documents/profiles/

Can you anyone please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Well, you're using a network path in what is supposed to be a file system path. The path that you see in URLs are not file system paths. They're just a hierarchical path which identifies a resource available over HTTP.

Comment: So, If I want to upload an image on server which option I need to use instead of Files.copy(Paths.get())

Comment: The answer is in the question: use a path that exists on the file system of the server, like `D:/documents/profile/`.

Comment: What about uploading an image to path http://www.example.com/documents/profile/ ?

Comment: Again, you're confusing an URL with a file system path. You store images wherever you want on the file system of the server (or in an external service, or a database, or wherever the server can store and find them). Then, if you want to display these images in your web app, you write a spring mvc controller, mapped to a path you choose and which has nothing to do with where you stored the images, and you load and serve the images from that controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the below solutions.

**Solution-1 :**
We can upload an image on our FileSystem using Path like "D://Documents/". We just need to add the path where we want to upload an image.

**Solution-2 :**
We can upload an image on Server fileSystem using IP like "file:////103.XXX.XX.XX//Documents/". We need to provide the path of our remote place with IP address.

**Solution-3 :**
We can upload an image on our hosting site using FTPClient (Java-Networking).
Following are the references :

- **For File Upload :**
  https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-upload-tutorial-and-example
- **For Delete File :**
  https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/delete-a-file-on-a-ftp-server
- **For checkDirectoryOrFileExistOrNot :**
  https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/determine-if-a-directory-or-file-exists-on-ftp-server